# SQL Display data from one table and count results from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a beginner in SQL. I am having problems with my assignment.

I need to write a Select statement that displays the following information. 
- Employee name (Ename)
- Employee IC number (EIC_NO)
- Total number of payment records
- Display the above information only for employees with >100 payment records

I think the problem is that the data I need to present belongs to 2 separate tables. The tables are structured as follow:

**Table 1 Name**
Employee
**Column names:**
Employee_ID    (primary key),
Ename          (secondary key),
EIC.

**Table 2 Name**
Payment
**Column names:**
PYMT_ID         (primary key),
PYMT_Timestamp,
PYMT_method,
Booking_id,
Emp_ID    (foreign key to Employee table, same as Employee_ID).

MY code is below. But it does not work.

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.ename, COUNT(p.emp_ID=e.employee_id)
FROM employee e, payment p
HAVING COUNT(p.emp_ID=e.employee_id) >100;
```

Appreciate if anyone can assist me on this. Thank you. :)

Comment: Look into INNER joins, dont use the comma separated table names, use joins

Comment: @Brad, OP is doing an inner join, an implicit one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `group by` to group all the payment emp_ID.

```
  select p.emp_ID, e.ename, COUNT(*)
    from employee e, payment p
   where p.emp_ID=e.employee_id
group by p.emp_ID, e.ename
  having count(*) > 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

Select e.employee_id AS ID, e.ename AS Name, COUNT(p.employee_id) AS TotalPaymentRecs

FROM Employees as e INNER JOIN Payments as p ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id

GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.ename

HAVING TotalPaymentRecs > 100

Comment: Don't just dump code alone, also provide an explanation what you did and why it works. Read more on [answer].

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT e.employee_Id, e.ename, COUNT(p.emp_id)
From Employee as e
INNER JOIN Payement as p
ON e.employee_id = p.emp_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.ename, p.emp_id
HAVING COUNT(p.emp_id) > 100
```

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions! Much appreciated! :)